# Is there an alternative to r10k or librarian-puppet that manages transitive dependencies

Tags: vagrant, puppet

I have a hard time dealing with the puppet modules of my Vagrant. This is mainly due to the fact that neither `r10k` nor `librarian-puppet` handle transitive dependencies. That is, if I have a Puppetfile that points to a puppet module which itself contains a Puppetfile, then this last Puppetfile is ignored.

Comment: could you please give a sample to explain how Puppetfile to point another Puppetfile?

Comment: Strictly speaking, a puppetfile pointing at a module that contains another puppetfile. Say your mypuppet module depends on puppet-concat which depends on puppet-stdlib.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this tool : https://github.com/backuity/puppet-module-installer

It is an asset to your private puppet infrastructure :)